# How to display all results from columns A with same values in Column B in php

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have database like

```
column A        Column B

2015-11-25      session 1
2015-11-26      session 1
2015-11-27      session 1
2015-11-28      session 2
```

I want to display like

```
Next session 1 is on - 25 Nov 2015, 26 Nov 2015, 27 Nov 2015
```

I tried GROUP BY column B but it is returning only one, first value. i.e. 25 Nov 2015.

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("select * from  table GROUP BY column B HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 order by column A ASC");
 while($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>

Next <?=$data['column B']?> Is On <b><?=date("d F Y",strtotime($data['coulmn A']));?>
<?}?>
```

Comment: try `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Comment: remove select * and use column names

Answer (score 2):

use `GROUP_CONCAT`,`concat` or `group by`

```
Select 
concat('Next ',b,' is on - ',GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(a,'%d %b %Y')))  
From table group by b
```

or `DATE_FORMAT` use for change you date format

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
 <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("select ColumnA, ColumnB from  table GROUP BY columnB, ColumnA HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 order by column A ASC");
     while($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>

    Next <?=$data['columnB']?> Is On <b><?=date("d F Y",strtotime($data['coulmnA']));?>
    <?}?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a simple way, but working..

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, "select columnB from  table GROUP BY columnB, columnB HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ");
while($data1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $ses = $data1['columnB'];
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "select columnA, columnB from table where columnB='$ses'");
    while($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
      var_dump($data2);
    }
}
```